# System of equations in 2 variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

A certain municipality recycled eight times as many tons of cardboard as aluminum in one year. If the total amount recycled was 936 ​tons, how much cardboard and how much aluminum was​ recycled?  Use system of equation in two variables

If the amount of cardboard recycled is equal to (c) and the amount of aluminum recycled is equal to (a), I tried using c + a = 936, but I do not know how to set up the other equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c$ represents the number of tons of cardboard recycled, and $a$ represents the number of tons of aluminum recycled, we should be able to write down two equations involving $c$ and $a$. One equation comes from "[they] recycled 8 times as many tons of cardboard as aluminum". That tells you that the number $c$ is equal to $8$ times the number $a$.

The other equation we need comes from the statement "the total amount recycled was 936 tons". That tells us something about the sum of $a$ and $c$.

Is that enough of a hint for you to write down the two equations?

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed response. If I understand your hint correctly, I have one equation that is (c)=8(a) and the other is (c) + (a) = 936? I am going to solve them to see if that works.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs I solved the system of equations using (c)=8(a) and (c) + (a) = 936 and I obtained c = 832 and a = 104, which are the correct answers. Thanks again  for your help.